# Web service call - underlying connection closed

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, iis-7, windows-server-2008

We have an ASP.NET web service, Framework 2.0 running under IIS 7 + Windows 2008. After working fine in Integration and QC the service has moved to production and any calls to the service bomb out. We added a test method that returns a string- this works but the others that take complex types don't. Here is the stack trace:

> `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.  System.Web.Services     at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)     at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)     at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)     at`
>
> httpett.log says: Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue

We've tried switching to classic mode, re-registering ASP.NET and are now considering rolling it out in prod on W2003.

Any ideas anyone?